# Migrate axios to fetch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, fetch

I have an axios post call:

```
export async function createFriend ({
  let myData = new FormData()
  myData.append('name', name)
  myData.append('age', age)
  const response = await axios.post('/myApi/friends', myData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  })
  return response.data.id
}
```

I want to migrate this to a fetch call:

```
export async function createFriend ({
  let myData = new FormData()
  myData.append('name', name)
  myData.append('age', age)

  const response = await fetch('/myApi/friends', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    data: myData
  })
  return response.data.id
}
```

However i'm getting the following error: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. But this didnt happen in the axios call. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're assuming that the shape of a `fetch` response object is the same as the shape of an `axios` response object.

Comment: could you assisting with the correct response object from a fetch call?

Answer (score 2):

`fetch` returns a promise that has a `.json()` method which you need to await.

So you need to change `return response.data.id` to `return (await response.json()).id`;

Here is a full code sample from your question with the fix applied:

```
export async function createFriend ({
  let myData = new FormData()
  myData.append('name', name)
  myData.append('age', age)

  const response = await fetch('/myApi/friends', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    data: myData
  })

  return (await response.json()).id
}
```